# Autoplay CSS3 Slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I modified a pre-designed slideshow that I found [here](http://cssdeck.com/item/458/css3-image-slider) and I would like to edit it so that it autoplays without the user having to click the arrows. I'm not sure how to do this, however. Can you simulate clicks with jQuery? Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. It gets the current slide and advances every 3.5 seconds. This works specifically for 4 slides instead of the 5 slides that are shown in the tutorial. My script also accounts for reaching the final slide and looping back to the first one, as well as advancing from the *most current* slide if the user advances them on his/her own.

Each slide looks like this...

```
<input value="0" type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
```

...with the checked = "checked" on the current slide. The value is 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n for each slide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tmp = 0;
        $(document).ready(
            function() { 
                tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
                var tid = setInterval(advance, 3500);
            }
        );

        function advance() {
            if(tmp == 3) {
                $('input[name=controls]:eq(0)').attr('checked', 'checked');
                tmp = 0;
            }
            else { 
                $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp+1) + ')').attr('checked', 'checked'); 
                tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
            }
        }

        function abortTimer() { clearInterval(tid); }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

He said he is using the `checked` attribute of the radio buttons.

> I used radio input buttons and their labels with the :checked pseudo
>   class to control the sliding images. So if you change from one image
>   to another the browser doesn't create a step in the browser history
>   (like in other CSS slideshows).
>
> Have fun with my slider :)

So you could just create a loop with JQuery that goes through the array of checkboxes.  You can get an array  of the checkboxes using the [checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and iterate which radio button is currently checked, by finding the currently checked radio button using the [checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.

Comment: I'll try this out and report back. Thanks, Alex.